# LLM fine tunning

Tags: large-language-model

Anyone can give some idea why do we need "prepare_model_for_kbit_trainin" to prepare the model before training. I see some notebook they used and some case they don't use. I just wanted to know what will be differences if I used or not used? Note, this method only works for transformers models. Please enlighten me if you have some ideas?

I tried to google it and see what will be differences but don't get enough resources.

Comment: Take a look at the source code, it has quite a few comments: https://github.com/huggingface/peft/blob/main/src/peft/utils/other.py#L75